# 3 phase or single phase

Tags: power

Hi new be to this site hope you can help.

[image]

I have a 3 phase vacuum pump on the motor plate it says
50 Hz 175-260/300-450. Does this mean if we rewire to star or delta we can use it on 50 Hz 240 volt single phase. I hope you can help, thank you.

Comment: A 3-phase system with 240V between neutral and phase has 415V between two phases. But it requires 3-phase system, it can't work on a single phase system. Does that help?

Comment: You need phase shifting capacitor to run with single phase.

Comment: Run capacitor may work. Better approach would be a VFD to give 3phase directly.

Answer (score 2):

> *does this mean we can use it on 50 Hz
> 240 volt \$\boxed{\text{single phase}}\$.*

No, because it is a 3 phase motor.

Answer (score 0):

No, a three-phase motor requires a three-phase supply. The three phases are 120° apart and create a rotating magnetic field in the motor and the rotor "chases" this.

With a single phase connection there is no rotating field and therefore no rotating torque. The motor will hum for a while and then will emit smoke.

If you only have a single phase supply you could use a small variable-frequency drive (VFD) to run the pump. You may find that it is cheaper to replace the motor with a single-phase model of the same power rating.